# How do I reattach pool tiles?

Tags: tile, pool, grout

The following tiles:

[image: tiles]

Have fallen off the side of the swimming pool here:

[image: swimming pool]

Questions: What should I use to stick them back on? I notice that they appear to have grouting between them. Is that a different substance to that which is used to stick them back? How do I prevent more from falling off and having to go through the exercise of lowering the pool level again to reattach?